# Android Gradle: get return value from a static java method

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle

I need to use a method from one of my java classes in build time, like you can do in ant like this:

```
<target name="getString" >
    <property file="project.properties" /> <!-- Load the ${target} platform property -->
    <script language="javascript" classpath="../ProjectName/bin/randomJar.jar:../otherProject/binrandomClass.jar:../otherProject2/bin/randomJar2.jar:/fff/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platforms/${target}/android.jar">
    <![CDATA[
        importClass(com.example.sdk.ExampleClass);
        returnString = ExampleClass.thisIsTheMethod(null);
        project.setProperty("blah", returnString);
    ]]>
    </script>
</target>
```

I dont want to run a Main method like iv'e seen in other answers, just a static method and get the return string.

thank you.

Comment: I need more information about what you want to do. What is the structure of the project? why you want to do that and think there is no other way to do so? Is for you an option creating a gradle plugin to do this?

Comment: first of all thank you. second of all plugin is not an option, structure doesn't matter, I need an example and ill take it from there, and I don't think there is no way otherwise I wouldn't ask for an answer. the return string is for making docs for an sdk

Comment: The thing is, there are many ways to get information from somewhere with gradle, but I don't think you can execute just part of your code. You can do many things like, set an environment to get this variable, provide it as an argument in the gradle execution, parse some file to get this value or even parse your java file. But you can't simply execute some random code you don't have compiled and packaged properly somehow.

Comment: We can open a chat to see which is the most suitable way for your case

Comment: well first I can do it at the end of build time, second it is possible with ant, third its a static code so I should be able to. Thank you